# Remix: Trouble naming a function parameter?

Tags: solidity, cpp-ethereum

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract SignatureStatus
{
    string documentIDhash;
    struct Signature {
        string documentID; //ID of the document
        string studyID; // ID of the study the document is associated with
        string timeStamp; // Timestamp of the signature
        bool consented; //  boolean of the consent status
    }


//sets the consent status of the contract
function consentBuild(documentIDhash,studyIDhash,timeStamphash,consentedhash) public returns (Signature)
{
string documentID = documentIDhash;
string studyID = studyIDhash;
string timeStamp = timeStamphash;
bool consented = consentedhash;


 }
    //checks the status of the contract
    function Status() returns (bool status) 
    {
    //bool consented = true;    
    if (consented == true) {status = true;} else {status = false;}
    }
```

This is my current contract, I'm trying to create a public function that receives a tx call from web3 js and stores the parameters in a struc. I'm getting this error however whenever I try to name my parameters in the function. I've tried defining the parameters beforehand and that isn't working either. What exactly am I not seeing/missing to simply set my function parameter names?

```
browser/Untitled.sol:15:27: TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract.
function consentBuild(documentIDhash,studyIDhash,timeStamphash,consentedhash) public returns (Signature)
                      ^------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

In solidity when you declare a function you have to put the type of each parameter before the parameter. Something like this should work

```
function consentBuild(
    string documentIDhash, 
    string studyIDhash, 
    string timeStamphash, 
    bool consentedhash) public returns (Signature) {
// Rest of you function ...
```